# Are there any ways to limit SSL renegotations through openssl library

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

The negotiation process of the SSL encryption uses significantly more resources on the server than on the client. If the client can initiate the renegotiation process, an attacker can render the server unavailable with a Denial of Service attack [DoS].I want to configure the number of SSL renegotiation attempts to prevent a server from DoS attacks.
By setting SSL_OP_NO_RENEGOTIATION option flag in SSL_CTX_set_options(), the renegotiation can be completely disabled. Are there any other ways to restrict the attempts without completely disabling it ?